# What is the meaning of the version numbers in an output of "pod outdated"?

Tags: cocoapods

I have executed "pod outdated" for my project. This is the output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
The following pod updates are available:
- Kingfisher 4.0.0 -> 4.0.0 (latest version 4.2.0)
- Lokalise 0.7.0 -> 0.7.0 (latest version 0.7.1)
- LokaliseLiveEdit 0.2.2 -> 0.2.2 (latest version 0.2.3)
- Realm 3.0.0 -> 3.0.0 (latest version 3.0.2)
- RealmSwift 3.0.0 -> 3.0.0 (latest version 3.0.2)
- SwiftLint 0.23.0 -> 0.23.0 (latest version 0.24.0)
- SwiftyJSON 3.1.4 -> 3.1.4 (latest version 4.0.0)
- Tabman 1.0.6 -> 1.0.6 (latest version 1.0.7)
```

What is the meaning of the version numbers which are presented three times per line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, this is the scheme of a line of `pod outdated`'s output:

```
- <pod name> <current version> -> <latest version (with restrictions)> (latest version <latest version (without restrictions)>)
```

The first version number (before the arrow) is the **current version** of a Pod.

The second number (after the arrow) is the latest available version **according to the restrictions in your Podfile**.

The third version number (inside the brackets, after "latest version") is the latest available version **without the personal restrictions**.

From [CocoaPods Guides](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html):

> When you run `pod outdated`, CocoaPods will list all pods which have newer versions than the ones listed in the `Podfile.lock` (the versions currently installed for each pod). This means that if you run `pod update PODNAME` on those pods, they will be updated — **as long as the new version still matches the restrictions** like `pod 'MyPod', '~>x.y'` set in your `Podfile`.

Comment: BTW, what does `pod outdated` do?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz It lists all possible pod updates