# How do I list all my pods and their version number

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

Basically I want to see what's in the `pod` file, but from the `terminal`. I have tried `$pod list`, but that seems to create an infinit loop listing I don't know what. If I locate the local `pod` file there are just a few `pods` installed.

I have read a few other treads on `SO`, like this: [How to find out the version of installed cocoa pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677830/how-to-find-out-the-version-of-installed-cocoa-pods)

`$pod --version` gives the cocoa version I suppose
`$pod outdated --help` only show those pods that are outdated

And I have also tried a bunch of other commands that show something else than I want to. Seems to me that there isn't a way to just list your pods unless I'm using `pod list` the wrong way. If there is no way to just list my pods and their version number let me know.

Comment: Take a look at the file `Podfile.lock`, which lists the dependencies. You should find it in the same directory as your Podfile.

Comment: @JanSchlorf Yes, I know, but I want to see it in the terminal, not locally. Or did you mean that I should open Podfile.lock in the terminal some way?

Comment: You could just view the file's contents with `cat Podfile.lock`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run

```
pod outdated
```

on the terminal. This will list your pod's current version and it will show the latest version of each pod, like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell what is the meaning of red color?

Comment: Check it out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325478/12063370

Comment: This will only list outdated pods though not ALL pods.

Answer (score 0):

green - Will be updated to the newest version.

blue - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of specified version in Podfile.

red - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile.